# Add year to count up

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble adding in a year to my count up code.

I have tried this:

```
days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1);
days=Math.floor(difference/(60*60*1000*24)*1/365);
hours=Math.floor((difference%(60*60*1000*24))/(60*60*1000)*1/365);
mins=Math.floor(((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))/(60*1000)*1/365);
secs=Math.floor((((difference%(60*60*1000*24))%(60*60*1000))%(60*1000))/1000*1/365);

document.getElementById('countup').setAttribute("uptime",years+':'days+':'+hours+':'+mins+':'+secs)
document.getElementById('years').firstChild.nodeValue = years;
document.getElementById('days').firstChild.nodeValue = days;
document.getElementById('hours').firstChild.nodeValue = hours;
document.getElementById('minutes').firstChild.nodeValue = mins;
document.getElementById('seconds').firstChild.nodeValue = secs;
```

But it still didn't work. Also how would I allow for a leap year?

Working fiddle without year below:

https://jsfiddle.net/ma9ic/3jxm4e7t/

Can someone point me in the right direction. Is there an easier method for creating the same effect with jQuery?

Comment: I would recommend using a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) rather than trying to reinvent the wheel. Otherwise, the calculation you'd need will be way more complicated than what you have so far.

Comment: jQuery is a DOM manipulation library so it's of absolutely no help for manipulating dates.

Comment: take a look, i edit your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jxm4e7t/1/

Comment: That's cool @Frogmouth, although I think what OP is asking for is about accurately calculating the time between two dates (Years, Months, Days, Hours, and Seconds) whilst accounting for leap years/seconds.

Comment: @Frogmouth No worries. I do like what you did though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to have a rough time trying to create this in plain JS and jQuery isn't really an appropriate option as it's primarily a DOM manipulation library.

#### Instead, I recommend using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

It's a library dedicated to this sort of thing and handles things which you probably weren't even thinking about (like Timezones).

Just [browse through the code and see what I mean](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/moment.js).